# Nest can't resolve dependencies of repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I got error on my nestjs app. I cant figure out whats wring with my code. I 
The codes is something like this

**AppModule**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AdminModule } from './components/admin.modules';

@Module({
    imports: [
        AdminModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
          username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
          password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
          database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
          port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
        }),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**AdminModule**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { Admin } from './admin.entity';
import { AdminRepository } from './admin.repository';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Admin])],
    providers: [AdminRepository],
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

**AdminRepository**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { RepositoryBase } from '../../common/base/repository.base';
import { Admin } from './admin.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AdminRepository extends RepositoryBase<Admin> {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(Admin) private readonly repo: Repository<Admin>) {
        super(repo);
}
```

And what i get is error like this

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AdminRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument AdminRepository at index [0] is available in the AdminModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>   - If AdminRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AdminModule?
>   - If AdminRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AdminModule?

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a repository.base file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem is the name you are giving to the provider: `AdminRepository`. Quite likely, internally `TypeOrm` is using that name to create a repository for the `Admin` entity and hence the name clash.

If you rename your provider class to anything else, (e.g. `AdminRepo` or `AdminService`), the error should go away.
Or another thing to do would be to rename the entity class from `Admin` to something else.

What you want to avoid is creating a class with `${EntityClassName}Repository`

Comment: Damn... reserved names should throw an error or something.